# What does 'sweep' mean in the context "The Taliban swept to power"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

My question is brief : What does 'sweep' mean in the context "The Taliban swept to power"?

I sweep the floors at work everyday but not once have I *swept* to power.

Comment: It is an idiomatic expression. ***sweep to​/​from power*** 
to win or lose an election by a very large number of votes
*The Party swept to power in elections the following year.* 
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sweep-to-from-power

Comment: Most dictionaries have multiple metaphorical meanings of [to sweep](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sweep) that are beyond the literal 'action of a broom'.

Comment: *The runners swept past us*. In such contexts, ***sweep*** just means ***move swiftly***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *sweep* is often used to evoke a sense of speed and completeness. In the phrase *sweep to power* it means a quick and complete victory.

Consider the following:

"Sweeping changes" - broad and drastic changes

"Swept to victory" - win in a quick and clear manner

"Swept aside" - forced into the sidelines